# While will not end after user enters

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application, user-input, console.writeline

Everything runs fine. However, I need the loop to end contingent upon how many numbers the user enters in the first question.

```
using System;

namespace Looping
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you provide?");
            int numbersProvide = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int i = 0;

            while (i <= numbersProvide)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter number:");
                int firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                int j;
                int sum = 0;
              
                double addDiv;

                for (j = 1; j <= 25; j++)
                {
                    
                    if (firstNum % j == 0)
                    {
                       addDiv = firstNum / j;
                       Console.WriteLine(firstNum + " is divisible by " + j + "(" + addDiv + ")");
                        sum += j;

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The sum of the quotient is: " + sum);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding I will note everything you are saying. The for loop actually gave me what I wanted. I should have mentioned this in the post but I was also concerned with if the user decides to enter more then number after the loop ends it still says "Please enter a number" when it should say "Please enter number 2" and so forth? Any immediate advice?

Answer (score 1):

You set `int i = 0;` and `i` never increases. Nor does `numbersProvide` decrease.

Since you have a fixed amount of times that the loopo shall run, a `for` loop is much more suitable for the situation than the `while` loop you have. Use `while` loops if you don't know how often the loop will run. Use `for` loops, if you know the number of runs in advance.

A typical for loop will combine your declaration (`int i=0`), the condition (`i <= numbersProvide`) and the missing increment (`i++`) in one line.

```
for (int i=0; i<=numbersProvide; i++)
```

When seeing that, I immediately recognize that the loop is off by one and it should be

```
for (int i=0; i<numbersProvide; i++)
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for responding I will note everything you are saying. The for loop actually gave me what I wanted. I should have mentioned this in the post but I was also concerned with if the user decides to enter more then number after the loop ends it still says "Please enter a number" when it should say "Please enter number 2" and so forth? Any immediate advice?

Comment: I always like to get feedback on my progress, so yes, having "Enter number x of y" makes it a better usability. If the user shall be able to enter arbitrarily many numbers, then don't ask for the amount in advance and let him enter "E" for End or something. In that case you'd use a while loop `while (userInput != "E")` or something.